# Gulp: preserving folder structure on destination for individual files

Tags: gulp

Let’s say we have the following folder structure:

```
rootDirectory
     │
     │
     ├──a
     │  ├──a.txt
     │
     ├──b
     │  ├──a
     │     ├──a.txt
     │
     ├──c.txt
```

also, let’s say we need to write a Gulp task that will take `a.txt` in the `a` folder, and `c.txt`; perform some manipulations on them, and then pipe them into the `build` directory. What I want is for the files copied in the build folder to keep their directory structure in the `build` folder (and I do not want files that were not supposed to be processed by the task to get in the `build` folder), like so:

```
rootDirectory
     │
     │
     ├──a
     │  ├──a.txt
     │
     ├──b
     │  ├──a
     │     ├──a.txt
     │
     ├──c.txt
     │
     ├──build
          │
          ├──a
          │  ├──a.txt
          │          
          ├──c.txt
```

Now, here is what puzzles me. If I specify paths to specific files:

```
gulp.task('foo', function(){
    var files = [
        path.join(__dirname, 'c.txt'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'a/a.txt')
    ];
    gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(__dirname, build));
});
```

then I will flatten the folder structure in the `build` directory.

If, however, I use the globbing pattern:

```
gulp.task('foo', function(){
    var files = [
        path.join(__dirname, '**/c.txt'),
        path.join(__dirname, '**/a/a.txt')
    ];
    gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(__dirname, build));
});
```

then the folder structure is preserved, but this globbing pattern will also target `b/a.txt`, which I do not want.

Is there a way to achieve what I describe in Gulp? Basically, telling Gulp: "Here, take this file, do whatever you need with this, and put it in another path keeping the folder structure starting from this root path"? **Apart from** specifically negating globbing paths that I do not want to match?

Comment: this may help: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/151

Comment: @sobolevn: do you mean using the `base` parameter? (`gulp.src(["blah-blah"], {base: "."})`)? I need to try that; looks promising.

Comment: Yay, the `base` option passed as the second argument to gulp.src works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to preserve hierarchy you should pass [{base: "."}](https://gulpjs.org/API.html#options-base) parameter to the gulp.src. Something like this:

```
gulp.task('foo', function(){
    var files = [
        path.join(__dirname, 'c.txt'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'a/a.txt')
    ];
    gulp.src(files, {base: '.'})
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(__dirname, build));
});
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I eventually did. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're just passing '.' as the second argument.  Shouldn't that be {base:'.'} ?

Comment: @light24bulbs is right, it has to be `{base: '.'}` instead of just a dot