# Gulp - compile scss files in subfolders

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have main folder that is running gulp server, and it contains projects with separate files. I'd like to make gulp watch subfolders and compile scss files for other projects too, not only for currently running. I add "watch" for subfolders, when I change scss in subfolders it says "injected: main.css", but doesn't alter "main.css".

Structure of my folders:

```
BASE/scss
    /projects/project1/scss
             /project2/scss
             /projects3/scss
```

I want to basically made possible to run gulp on BASE folder and watch and compile all .scss files separately in all scss folders shown above - for base folder and projects in subfolder.

How to make that scss -> css compilation for subfolders too ?

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
          .pipe(autoprefixer('last 10 versions', '>0.5%'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: ".",
        notify: {
            styles: {
                top: 'auto',
                bottom: '0'
            }
        }
    });

    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']); // main folder
    gulp.watch('./projects/**/scss/*.scss', ['sass']); // added for subfolders, 
   // detects changes in files but doesn't making css output
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for could mean many things. So I'll start by describing what your gulp task tells me you are doing:

*Your gulp task will watch for any changes to .scss files found immediately under `BASE/scss/` and for changes to .scss files found immediately under any directory called `scss/` where the directory is a sub-directory (recrusive) of `BASE/projects/`. When a change is detected to any of those files, your 'sass' task will be run, compiling just the .scss files found immediately under `BASE/scss/` (non-recursively). It places the compiled .css in `BASE/css/`. It will not compile any files found under `BASE/projects/`.*

What this means is that any .scss file found under `BASE/projects` will not be compiled unless it is `@import`ed by a file found immediately under `BASE/scss/`.

The first problem that sticks out to me is what your providing to `gulp.src`. It looks like `gulp.src('scss/*.scss')` is only including .scss files found directly under `BASE/scss/`.

You can include the files under `BASE/PROJECTS` by adding it to the `gulp.src` call in the 'sass' task using

```
gulp.src([
    'scss/*.scss',
    './projects/**/scss/*.scss'
])
```

I have recreated this scenario given your 'sass' task and the directory structure you describe. This argument to `gulp.src` works perfectly using gulp v3.9.1.

The next question I have is what is `main.css`? I would not expect a file called `main.css` to be output to `BASE/css/` unless there is a file at `BASE/scss/main.scss`.

If all of this is working (like it does in my tests) and you still don't see the correct files being compiled, there are additional options.

You may want to expand your glob patterns to match files recursively. This can be done with the following patterns

```
gulp.src([
    'scss/**/*.scss',
    './projects/**/scss/**/*.scss'
])

gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); // main folder
gulp.watch('./projects/**/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
```

`**/*.scss` globs match all .scss files recursively under a directory. `*.scss` only matches .scss file immediately under a directory.

If all else fails, I would suggest isolating your compilation problem outside of `gulp.watch`. Strip out all extraneous code and build up the functionality line by line to ensure you are achieving the appropriate results.

Comment: I don't want to concatenate output, I just need to scss->css on multiple projects that are subfolders of a base project. I updated my question with my folders tree. Answer doesn't work, there should be "{" instead of "[", but even after fixing that it prints "Unexpected token ,". There is no error if I change it both to "[]" but it still doesn't work with creating css output.

Comment: @norbidrak Just saw the typo. Sorry about that. I fixed it in the answer

Comment: I added path to src as you said, but now the weird thing is that it takes scss files from subfolders and compile them to css files into BASE/css/projectX/scss/main.css not in their relative path as it suppose to do, like BASE/projects/projectX/css/main.css. And it creates immediately folders for all my projects in BASE/css folder, it's like there is something wrong with gulp.dest, cause it's taking static path as an output. You were asking about main.css, I have the same structure for BASE and projects- all having their own main.scss to compile: scss/main.scss -> css/main.css

Comment: Maintaining directory structure is another problem altogether. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220618/gulp-preserving-folder-structure-on-destination-for-individual-files